# Overlaying an image onto Rayshader map so that they are aligned

Tags: r, gis, rayshader

The below code gets the elevation data for an area in London and the equivalent bing map.
I plot the elevation code using rayshader and overlay the bing map however they don't match up.
This is because the bing map dimensions don't match the rayshader map. I could change the dimensions via the width and height variables on the png function and get them to match using trial and error. However I would like to do this programatically without the need for such manual tweaking.

```
library(elevatr)
library(rayshader)
library(OpenStreetMap)

#london bbox
mapextent<-c(51.477482,-0.120438,51.527517,0.051910)

#get elevation data
elev_data <- get_elev_raster(
  locations = data.frame(x = c(mapextent[2],mapextent[4]), y = c(mapextent[1],mapextent[3])),
  z = 10,
  prj = "EPSG:4326",
  clip = "bbox")
elev_mat<-raster_to_matrix(elev_data)

#create bing png to overlay
png("bing_map.png")

map<-openmap(upperLeft=c(mapextent[1], mapextent[2]), 
             lowerRight=c(mapextent[3],mapextent[4]), 
             type = "bing")

plot(map)
dev.off()
bing_map <- png::readPNG("bing_map.png")

#put together in a 3d map
elev_mat %>%
  sphere_shade() %>%
  add_overlay(bing_map, alphalayer = 0.9) %>%
  plot_3d(elev_mat, zscale = 10, fov = 0, theta = 0, phi = 60,
          windowsize = c(600, 450),
          zoom = 0.7,
          background = "lightgrey")
```

This is how the map looks, you can see that the bing map is too narrow.

[image]

Does anyone know how to get the dimensions of the rayshader map in advance so I can then pass these to the png function? Im aware there are other ways to overlay maps but I want to use the above method.

Comment: You are saving the file as `"bing_map.png"` but reading in `"osm_map.png"`. Perhaps this isn't the source of the issue but it's not going to help...

Comment: Its a typo, irrelevant to the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Every entry in elev_mat is a point in the rendered image. So

```
height=nrow(elev_mat)
width=ncol(elev_mat)
```